# pubcenter integration Windows 8.1 Store - An error occurred

Tags: windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, ads

I am developing Win 8.1 Store App, I am integrating the pubCenter Ads as instructed by Microsoft in this link [pubCenter Integration with Visual Studio 2013 - Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn284011(v=msads.10).aspx), but on clicking OK on Step 10, this error occur. I have properly signed-in with my Microsoft account. How to get rid of this.

see the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you cannot create new application and adunit in PubCenter for now. PubCenter has been integrated into Windows Dev Center.

> Note: You will no longer be able to create ad units or new app promotion campaigns in pubCenter. For information on how to create ad units in Dev Center, see Monetize with ads. For information on how to create app promotion campaigns in Dev Center, see Create an ad campaign for your app.

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186437.aspx for details.

Comment: Thx for the detailed link, there is much contents inside, which is very helpful. I am using Microsoft Ads Control in Widnows 8.1 Store App, Is this control also no longer available and we must use the AdMediator instead.??? Or I can still use the old Ads Control. plz.

Comment: I have created the Ad Units in Dev Center, now what should I do, how to implement it inside my App to display.

Comment: You can use Ad Control in Windows 8.1 Store App. AdMediator is an option. The latest Microsoft Universal Ad Client SDK supports AdMediator and Ad Control.

1. What's the differences between AdMediator and AdControl?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt463352(v=msads.30).aspx
2. Using Ad Control in Windows 8.1 app
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-walkthroughs-blend.aspx